# How to calculate capacitance analytically?

Tags: sensor, capacitance

Im developing a capacitive sensor of concentric cylindrical plates type.I know its dimensions(length & diameter). How i can calculate its capacitance without using any multi-meter or LCR-meter?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as for a length of coax: -

[image]

[image]

Information taken from [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html)

Where "L" is the length of the "tube" and "k" is the dielectric constant aka \$\epsilon_r\$.

See also [this](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/coax.htm) website.

Comment: not getting the same answer as the value calculated by the website

Comment: How long/round is the sensor and what frequency are you using? Also "not getting the same answer" is meaningless - put some numbers on it. Explain in detail how you measure it.

Comment: length is 146mm, od=50mm, id=16mm, dielectric is air only so constant is 1.and why frequency is required when we are calculating from formula?

Comment: I get 48.8 pF/m or 7.128 pF for 146 mm. What did you calculate and what did you measure? Frequency is important - ever heard of transmission line effects? Too high a frequency will turn your capacitor into an inductor. At 146 mm your "capacitor" will have an impedance of zero ohms with a frequency of about 600 MHz. Even at one-tenth of this there will be an error due to reflections.